# Json parsing in android from URL

Tags: android, json

I m getting json from URL but getting error in parsing. It is saying illegal character. Can you guys point out where is the culprit? 
**MyCode**

```
public String GetJString(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();          

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    Log.d("cstch",json);

        return json;

}
```

**Error Message**

```
04-08 15:26:43.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1122): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
04-08 15:26:43.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1122): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-08 15:26:43.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
04-08 15:26:43.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
04-08 15:26:43.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
04-08 15:26:43.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
04-08 15:26:43.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-08 15:26:43.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-08 15:26:43.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-08 15:26:43.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-08 15:26:43.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-08 15:26:43.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1122): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 124: http://smkamran.com/~tvinfo/tvguide/box/getprogramlist?mediagroupId=9c476522-d771-4fcd-ae21-34b302c04e46&dateBegin=2013-04-08 00:00:00&dateEnd=2013-04-08 23:59:00&channelList=RBB
04-08 15:26:43.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:727)
04-08 15:26:43.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost.<init>(HttpPost.java:79)
04-08 15:26:43.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at com.smkamran.germantv.JSONParser.GetJString(JSONParser.java:80)
04-08 15:26:43.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at com.smkamran.germantv.ChannelDetails$GetDataFromServer.doInBackground(ChannelDetails.java:267)
04-08 15:26:43.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at com.smkamran.germantv.ChannelDetails$GetDataFromServer.doInBackground(ChannelDetails.java:1)
04-08 15:26:43.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-08 15:26:43.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

Comment: Json source http://5.39.219.67/~tvinfo/tvguide/box/getprogramlist?mediagroupId=9c476522-d771-4fcd-ae21-34b302c04e46&dateBegin=2013-04-08%2000:00:00&dateEnd=2013-04-08%2023:00:00&channelList=RTL

Comment: check here, http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#jsonformatter

Comment: i just entered URL in above..it is valid json..http://5.39.219.67/~tvinfo/tvguide/box/getprogramlist?mediagroupId=9c476522-d771-4fcd-ae21-34b302c04e46&dateBegin=2013-04-08%2000:00:00&dateEnd=2013-04-08%2023:00:00&channelList=RTL

Comment: copy your json and paste, then check.

Comment: Can you suggest any solution to it?

Comment: Seems to be an invalid Json. My add-on (JSONView 0.7 on Firefox ) doesn't recognize it as a Json at least. All the Json strings I have worked with were recognized so far.

Comment: Problem solved by adding URLEncoder.encode(URL). thanks for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid .

Got following error

Error: Parse error on line 1:
...1658","description":"(1658)Simones Wide
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

Some brackets are missing at this point .

1658","description":"(1658)
Simones Widerstand gegen\u00fcber David br\u00f6ckelt.

Answer (score 3):

As per the error message, it's an illegal character in the querystring part your URL. You should use [URLEncoder.encode()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) on that URL.